# Stripe login link URL does not work

Tags: node.js, npm, stripe-payments

I am following the project at [stripe-connect-rocketrides](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides), and running it on my own NodeJS server to try to learn how to integrate Stripe payments. I've setup pretty much everything,
 but am now running into an issue where the login link doesn't work.

To start, I have a Stripe Account ID that I have created for the user who logged in and stored in the database. Now, when I try to log the user in to the Stripe Dashboard, I know that I need to use the [Create Login Link API](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-dashboard) to fetch a URL from Stripe that I can redirect users to. The URL I get is: https://connect.stripe.com/express/somehash

The problem is, when I redirect users to https://connect.stripe.com/express/somehash, this is the response I get:

```
{
  "error": {
      "code": "unexpected_api_error",
      "message": "An unexpected error occurred",
      "type": "api_error"
  }
}
```

This is code in the project that redirects the users to that page:

```
router.get('/transfers', pilotRequired, async (req, res) => {
        const pilot = req.user;
        // Make sure the logged-in pilot had completed the Stripe onboarding.
        if (!pilot.stripeAccountId) {
             return res.redirect('/pilots/signup');
        }
       try {
           // Generate a unique login link for the associated Stripe account.
           const loginLink = await 
           stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(pilot.stripeAccountId);

           return res.redirect(loginLink.url);
       } catch (err) {
            console.log('Failed to create a Stripe login link.');
            return res.redirect('/pilots/signup');
      }
  });
```

I wonder if this is because the URL expired. But I always get the API error from Stripe as soon as I receive the URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: An "api_error" is generally something unexpected. If you're seeing that I'd write into Stripe and they can look into what's causing this response!